# Group BY MySQL- what column to use?

Tags: mysql

Hi I have the following result set. I need to find the min(diff) for each id(ex.2904 min is 36).If I use group by id it is not showing 36 as min

```
# id, id_contact,NAME,OPTENTION_DATE,SEND_DATE, diff
2904, 28,Version 2, 2014-11-05, 2014-12-11 16:45:41, 36
2904, 28, Version 1, 2014-09-01, 2014-12-11 16:45:41, 101
2903, 178,Version 2, 2014-11-05, 2014-12-09 16:06:39, 34
2903, 178,Version 1, 2014-09-01, 2014-12-09 16:06:39, 99
```

The query I have is

```
SELECT 
  email.id,
  a_email_contact.id_contact,
  email.subject,
  x.NAME,
  x.OPTENTION_DATE,
  email.SEND_DATE,
  min(DATEDIFF(email.SEND_DATE, x.OPTENTION_DATE)) as diff
FROM
  classification_element y,
  classification_version x ,
  email,a_email_contact
where
  x.id_project=y.id_project
  and y.id_project=11
  and y.id_company=3
  and y.ID_VERSION=x.id
  and email.SEND_DATE>x.OPTENTION_DATE
  and a_email_contact.id_email=email.id
group by email.ID
order by diff asc
```

On what column should I use group by?

The result of this query is

```
# id, id_contact, subject, NAME, OPTENTION_DATE, SEND_DATE, diff
2904, 28,Version 1, 2014-09-01, 2014-12-11 16:45:41, 36
2903, 178,Version 1, 2014-09-01, 2014-12-09 16:06:39, 34
2902, 168,Version 1, 2014-09-01, 2014-10-16 10:22:42, 45
```

Which is wrong because #2904 should have version 2 with 36 as diff but it shows version1 instead.

Comment: Please post the results.

Comment: You should `group by` everything in the `select` that is not an argument to an aggregation function.

Comment: It still shows the same output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on volume of records you are working with, it may not be the most optimal, but it should work -

```
SELECT
id,
min(diff)
FROM
(
SELECT 
  email.id,
  a_email_contact.id_contact,
  email.subject,
  x.NAME,
  x.OPTENTION_DATE,
  email.SEND_DATE,
  DATEDIFF(email.SEND_DATE, x.OPTENTION_DATE) as diff
FROM
  classification_element y,
  classification_version x ,
  email,a_email_contact
where
  x.id_project=y.id_project
  and y.id_project=11
  and y.id_company=3
  and y.ID_VERSION=x.id
  and email.SEND_DATE>x.OPTENTION_DATE
  and a_email_contact.id_email=email.id
order by diff asc
) tmp
group by id
```

Comment: This query seems to give me the results but will it cause any performance issues when i work with thousands of records? Thanks for the answer, btw

Comment: Really does depend on the number of records + the content each record holds. If record count > (approx.) 50k then it could cause performance problems. I'm no expert in SQL, this was just something off the top of my head. Happy to help, glad to know it worked for you.

Comment: Is there any way to do it in a single query?

Comment: None that I know of, that's a really late reply sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking below SQL gives you correct result.

```
    select   id,
  id_contact,
 subject,
NAME,
 OPTENTION_DATE,
  SEND_DATE,
  min(diff) as result
  from (
SELECT 
  email.id,
  a_email_contact.id_contact,
  email.subject,
  x.NAME,
  x.OPTENTION_DATE,
  email.SEND_DATE,
  min(DATEDIFF(email.SEND_DATE, x.OPTENTION_DATE)) as diff
FROM
  classification_element y,
  classification_version x ,
  email,a_email_contact
where
  x.id_project=y.id_project
  and y.id_project=11
  and y.id_company=3
  and y.ID_VERSION=x.id
  and email.SEND_DATE>x.OPTENTION_DATE
  and a_email_contact.id_email=email.id

order by diff asc) as a
group by ID
```

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks , this works ! But I had accepted the same answer in the above comment just now !